# Phonegap 3.0 android scrolling issue

Tags: cordova, scroll, android-webview

I have looked around and found a few questions where this has been a "bug" in previous versions of phonegap... Does this problem still exist? It feels stupid that I am spending some much debugging time on scrolling.. haha.

For those unfamiliar with the issue it seems that standard webView scroll will not work in Android... I have tried to implement a 3rd party library like iScroll but there are some funky things happening with the scroll functionality so I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution in phonegap 3.0.

T